# What permissions does a group need in order to publish to s3 via travisci

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-iam

I am in the process of moving all my sites off my server and onto s3. I had already moved them from being dynamic sites to being static so running a server is no longer necessary for operations.

The last site is my blog, it runs jekyll and I would rather not have to build locally to publish new content. I don't want to leave it up to github pages because I do not want to locked into jekyll.

All that to say that I am attempting to move the build process off of my jenkins server and onto travis ci. From the doc I think I have given the group the correct permissions but I have not gotten it to work without granting `"s3:*"` to the group/user.

This is my current iam group permission policy:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListMultipartUpload",
                "s3:RestoreObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::travis-s3-pub-test/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

The only permission that should be necessary based on the aws docs are:

```

```
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
```

```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer with some help from the sys-admin where I work, jfronza.

I was missing the *acl* portion of the policy.

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:RestoreObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::travis-s3-pub-test/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::travis-s3-pub-test/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

The *acl* portion is where the file permissions happen and since the files being uploaded need to be public they need this permission.

While the [Amazon docs on s3 policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) on this are quite bad, the [travisCI docs on working with s3](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/) are good and tell me exactly this if I saw them before I posted this.